# jquery add a class to selected element in same div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add a class(hide) to header class.But I need to add it only to the element that contains the button.not to every header class.I have written some JavaScript but it will add hide class to every header class in the code. How do I add only to selected one?
I can do it with this.

```
$('.button').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.container_outer').find('.Header').addClass('Hide');}
```

but I need to do it with a function.Is that possible?

```js
function addAclass(){
 $('.button').closest('.container_outer').find('.Header').addClass('Hide');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-context">
    <div class="container_outer">
        <div class="container_txt">
            <h4 class="Header" contenteditable="true">section 1</h4>
            <a href="#" class="containersave" >
        </div>
        <div class="container_icon"> <a class="button" onclick="addAclass()" href="#">button</a> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container_outer">
        <div class="container_txt">
            <h4 class="Header" contenteditable="true">section 2</h4>
            <a href="#" class="containersave" >
        </div>
        <div class="container_icon"> <a class="button" onclick="addAclass()" href="#">button</a> </div>
    </div>    
    <div class="container_outer">
        <div class="container_txt">
            <h4 class="Header" contenteditable="true">section 3</h4>
            <a href="#" class="containersave" >
        </div>
        <div class="container_icon"> <a class="button" onclick="addAclass()" href="#">button</a> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is `$(this).closest(...` not solving your problem?

Comment: Yeah, it's working. But I need to add it using a function.

Comment: Have tried to explain the issue and provide possible solution in my answer. Feel free to ask, if you have any queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change here:

```
function addAclass(button){
    $(button).closest('.container_outer').find('.Header').addClass('Hide');
}

<a class="button" onclick="addAclass(this)" href="#">button</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to an an arguement to your function. Do something like this

```js
function addAclass(obj){
 $(obj).closest('.container_outer').find('.Header').addClass('Hide');

}
```

```css
.Hide{
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-context">
    <div class="container_outer">
        <div class="container_txt">
            <h4 class="Header" contenteditable="true">section 1</h4>
            <a href="#" class="containersave" >
        </div>
        <div class="container_icon"> <a class="button" onclick="addAclass(this)" href="#">button</a> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container_outer">
        <div class="container_txt">
            <h4 class="Header" contenteditable="true">section 2</h4>
            <a href="#" class="containersave" >
        </div>
        <div class="container_icon"> <a class="button" onclick="addAclass(this)" href="#">button</a> </div>
    </div>    
    <div class="container_outer">
        <div class="container_txt">
            <h4 class="Header" contenteditable="true">section 3</h4>
            <a href="#" class="containersave" >
        </div>
        <div class="container_icon"> <a class="button" onclick="addAclass(this)" href="#">button</a> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not that working with Dynamic object. Is there a way to work with dynamic objects.

Comment: What do you mean by that ?

Answer (score 0):

In your code,

```js
$('.button').click(function() {
  function addAclass() {
    $(this).closest('.container_outer').find('.Header').addClass('Hide');
  }
}
```

Following are the issues:

- `addAclass` is a local function and will not be accessible on HTML.
- When you add handler, you are not passing any arguments to handler that you can use.

Following are few ways you can solve it:

1. You can pass element's reference to handler as argument.

```js
function addAclass(el) {
  $(el).closest('.container_outer').find('.Header').addClass('Hide');
}
```

```css
.Hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-context">
  <div class="container_outer">
    <div class="container_txt">
      <h4 class="Header" contenteditable="true">section 1</h4>
      <a href="#" class="containersave">
    </div>
    <div class="container_icon"> <a class="button" onclick="addAclass(this)" href="#">button</a> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container_outer">
    <div class="container_txt">
      <h4 class="Header" contenteditable="true">section 2</h4>
      <a href="#" class="containersave">
    </div>
    <div class="container_icon"> <a class="button" onclick="addAclass(this)" href="#">button</a> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container_outer">
    <div class="container_txt">
      <h4 class="Header" contenteditable="true">section 3</h4>
      <a href="#" class="containersave">
    </div>
    <div class="container_icon"> <a class="button" onclick="addAclass(this)" href="#">button</a> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

2. You can create handler in JS using jQuery. It will bind context automatically:

Issue with this code:

```
$('.button').closest('.container_outer').find('.Header').addClass('Hide');
```

is that, your selector is incorrect. `$('.button')` will select every button.

```js
$('.button').on('click', function addAclass(el) {
  $(this).closest('.container_outer').find('.Header').addClass('Hide');
})
```

```css
.Hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-context">
  <div class="container_outer">
    <div class="container_txt">
      <h4 class="Header" contenteditable="true">section 1</h4>
      <a href="#" class="containersave">
    </div>
    <div class="container_icon"> <a class="button" href="#">button</a> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container_outer">
    <div class="container_txt">
      <h4 class="Header" contenteditable="true">section 2</h4>
      <a href="#" class="containersave">
    </div>
    <div class="container_icon"> <a class="button" href="#">button</a> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container_outer">
    <div class="container_txt">
      <h4 class="Header" contenteditable="true">section 3</h4>
      <a href="#" class="containersave">
    </div>
    <div class="container_icon"> <a class="button" href="#">button</a> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```